# How can I copy the cell format in an excel file across a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have got this excel sheet (image linked above) and I need to update it monthly, and as you can see, each month there is a new column with new numbers. After spending a while trying to get to grips with vba, and asking around, I gratefully got this code:

```
Sub Increment_Month()


    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngRow As Long

    lngRow = ActiveCell.Row
    lngLastCol = Cells(lngRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If IsDate(Cells(lngRow, lngLastCol)) Then
        With Union(Cells(3, lngLastCol + 1), Cells(17, lngLastCol + 1), Cells(32, lngLastCol + 1))
            .Value = DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(Cells(lngRow, lngLastCol)))
            .NumberFormat = Cells(lngRow, lngLastCol).NumberFormat
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

This increments the months for me so i can tap a button and it has the next month as a header. I am now stuck on how to paste the formatting of the previous months for the next months along i.e. have one macro that updates the format, without having to copy the format for each month (borders, colour headers in etc), but the macro i got just overwrites the last months data without going along by a month.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense (feel free to make me clarify it).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would it not suffice to just grab the format one, and apply it to the whole width of the sheet? There are only so many months you can have in there.

Comment: yes i suppose it would, but it just makes it as tidy as possible. thanks for your suggestion and edits, i appreciate it!

Comment: You could, instead of copying it, also have a button that inserts it from scratch. Both would work. I have never used VBA before, so have no idea how to do either though. Just happened to click the question by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will copy the last column to the right and clear the contents. It will then add one month to the previous date, and copy your sum formula(if you have a sum formula). I only looped through row 7 to cover your first set of data, you can change as required.

```
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Columns(lCol).Copy
Columns(lCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns(lCol + 1).ClearContents

    For Each cell In Range(Cells(3, lCol), Cells(7, lCol))
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, cell.Value)
        End If

        If cell.HasFormula = True Then
            cell.Copy
            cell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        End If
    Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA lets you change the background color of cells using the following syntax.
The below line of code will let you set the color of cells A1 and A10 to deep blue.

```
Range("A1,A10").Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 125)
```

You could use a similar syntax to get the range and set the background color.